# How to read from PDF and save as CSV, using Python?

Tags: python, csv, pdf, web-scraping, data-extraction

There is this URL https://www.jpx.co.jp/english/listing/stocks/new/index.html#3422

I wrote(copy&paste from internet!) the following code to save all the pdfs which are inside the table in a folder

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import io
import urllib.request as req
import urllib
import os
import time
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = 'https://www.jpx.co.jp/english/listing/stocks/new/index.html'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
res = req.urlopen(url) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, "html.parser") 
result = soup.select("a[href]") 

link_list =[] 
for link in result: 
    href = link.get("href") 
    link_list.append(href) 

pdf_list = [temp for temp in link_list if temp.endswith('pdf')]
print(pdf_list)

abs_pdf_list = []
for relative in pdf_list:
    temp_url = urljoin(url, relative)
    abs_pdf_list.append(temp_url)

filename_list = []
for target in abs_pdf_list:
    temp_list = target.split("/")
    filename_list.append(temp_list[len(temp_list)-1])

newpath = r'/Users/myfolder/python/IPO' 
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

target_dir = "/Users/myfolder/python/IPO/"
savepath_list = []
for filename in filename_list:
    savepath_list.append(os.path.join(target_dir, filename))
savepath_list

for (pdflink, savepath) in zip(abs_pdf_list, savepath_list):
        print(pdflink)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(pdflink, savepath)
        time.sleep(2)

import pdfplumber
import re

def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    
    with requests.get(url) as r:
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        
    return local_filename

ap_url = abs_pdf_list[0]

ap = download_file(ap_url)

with pdfplumber.open(ap) as pdf:
    page1 = pdf.pages[0]
    page2 = pdf.pages[1]  
    text = page1.extract_text()

print(text)
```

Now I need to read those pdfs and extract the below lines,

From page1
line which start with "Information & Communication"

From page2
lines which start with
"Book-building Period"
"Offering Price"

and  save them in one Excel or CSV file
Sadly I reached to my coding skill limit and can’t move any further .I convert the pdf to text,but …

Please advice me how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend installing our new package, [pdftextract](https://pypi.org/project/pdftextract/0.0.5/), that conserves the pdf layout as best as possible to extract text, then using some regex to extract the keywords.

Here's a working code snippet tested on 2 pdf files from your link:

```
import re
import csv
from pdftextract import XPdf

pdf_files = ['a.pdf', "b.pdf"]
keywords = ["Information & Communication", "Book-building Period", "Offering Price"]

def extract_infos(file:str, keywords:list):
    """extract the text from the pdf file then get the wanted keywords information"""
    # extracting the text from pdf while keeping the original layout
    pdf = XPdf(file)
    txt = pdf.to_text(keep_layout=True)
    row = []
    # getting the keywords information
    for keyword in keywords:
        # search for the keyword
        pattern = "{} (.+)\r".format(keyword) # extracting the wanted info
        regex = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.I| re.M)
        m = regex.search(txt)
        if m is not None:
            m = m.groups()[0].strip(' /\r') # strip unwanted space and characters
        row.append(m)
    return row

def main(files:list, fname:str, headers:list):
    """extract the wanted info from a bunch of pdf files and save them as csv file"""
    with open(fname, "w") as wf:
        writer = csv.writer(wf)
        writer.writerow(headers)

        for i, file in enumerate(files, start=1):
            row = extract_infos(file, headers)
            writer.writerow(row)

    print("[DONE]", "writed {} rows to {}.".format(i, fname))

main(pdf_files, "stocks.csv", keywords)
```

Comment: FYI this only runs on Windows